# How to check which attachment within the message matches the search

Tags: search, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to search outlook's message attachments where search content exist, and I'm using this Search parameter to search over user's messages : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#search-parameter.

But this api returns the details of the message where the search content exist, but does not specify the particular attachment within the message. I don't want to search on each attachment. goal is to search for the content from attachments from all the messages of the user and get the attachment details where search criteria meets.

This is the api call I'm using :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id>/messages?$search="abc"
```

I tried expending attachments with the search, but it returns all the attachments within this message, and not the one where the search content exist.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id>/messages?$search="abc"&$expand=attachments
```

I know there is another api for search on messages but it's in beta version : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-messages. I want an stable solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Since you are calling the /messages endpoint and using the search, the result would be the messages and the attachments would be searched again. You need to make an additional call to the /attachments endpoint by giving message id from the previous result and use search query parameter and then fetch the attachments.

Comment: I have tried it with txt which worked for me but it may or may not work with other extensions.

Comment: $Search query paratamter doesn't seem to work on attachments endpoint, I'm trying this:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id>/messages/<attachment-id/attachments/?$search="someText". But it's returning all the attachments of that message.

Comment: Yes, $Search is not supported on the attachments and there is a uservoice also raised on this [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40559788-ability-to-search-kw-in-mail-attachments-using-the). Please upvote this feature so that the Product team can implement it in the future.

Comment: So currently there is no way to figure out the exact attachment in the message where the search criteria meet ?

Comment: Yes, as of now you cannot do it from MS Graph side.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity Can we do it from outlook's rest APIs? or any other way? I was also looking forward to search for messages across tenant, I posted a separate question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238570/tenant-level-search-for-outlook-via-rest-api Kindly look into it as well. Thanks.